# How to choose data columns and target columns in a dataframe for test_train_split?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to set up a `test_train_split` with data I have read from a csv into a pandas dataframe. The book I am reading says I should separate into `x_train` as the data and `y_train` as the target, but how can I define which column is the target and which columns are the data? So far i have the following

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
Data = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
```

I have read to do the split in the following way however the following was using a bunch where the `data` and `target` were already defined:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(businessleisure_data['data'],
                                                    iris_dataset['target'], random_state=0)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
Data = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")    
X = Data.drop(['name of the target column'],axis=1).values
y = Data['name of the target column'].values
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,random_state=0)
```

In most cases, the target variable is the last column of the data set so you can also try this:

```
Data = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
X = Data.iloc[:,:-1]
y = Data.iloc[:,-1]
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,random_state=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for my problem, and this question came in search results.
Then I viewed the comment of [rrrrttt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12320458/rrrttt)
and found it useful. But some changes were required.

```
X = data.drop(['Outcome'],axis=1).values
y = data['Outcome'].values
X_train ,X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
```

Above mentioned is the code which was useful for me, which trained the Model on 80% data and tested it on 20% data.